# How to get Jakarta added to your project external libraries?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am new to Spring Boot but used Spring Initializr to create the shell of my project. I am part way through, but realized I am missing Maven: jakarta.validation-api:3.0.2 and all other Jakarta libraries when trying to add the validation portion to my form.

I have tried to add this

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to my pom.xml file and then run mvn clean install to update, but it does not recognize mvn command. I tried a few other answers on here to see if I could resolve it, including going to the Maven side panel and running the lifecyle library from there, but this didn't do anything to update either.

The spring-boot-maven-plugin is also red in this part of my pom file

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am on a mac using IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you do not have `mvn` installation.

> but it does not recognize mvn command

Usually, after `mvn` installation you would have

- `~/.m2/settings.xml` (user specific profiles) or/and
- `/usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml` (On linux)
- `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.7/libexec/conf/settings.xml` (On mac OS)

where you can define repositories from where you want to pull those packages. You can provide repositories in your `pom` as well. So for example, entry in the `settings.xml` would look like

```xml
...
<profiles>
 <profile>
      <id>maven</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>mavevn_central</id>
          <name>Default Repository</name>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
<\profiles>
...
```

Or in `pom.xml`

```xml
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mavevn_central</id>
            <name>Default Repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

When you will have this configuration, then in Intellij it is just:

1. Go to pom.xml
2. cmd + n --> to invoke `generate`
3. Choose `add dependency`
4. Search for dependency and select
5. Load maven changes

Default maven repository will be added after installation of `maven`.

More at [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

Comment: Default Maven repository is already defined in Maven ... why you try to redefine it?

Comment: I am not. This is just an example, you might add any repository, mirror, etc.

Comment: I modified my answer to make it less ambiguous.